# C++ Pointers assignment gives unexpected(?) results

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

```
int* snap = nullptr;
int last = -1;   
void func(int* md){
        if(snap!=nullptr) {
            last = *snap;
        }
        snap = md;
        cout<<last<< " "<<*snap<<endl;
    }
    
    int main() {
        
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++) {
            int arg = i;
            func(&arg);
        }
        return 0;
    }`
```

***Output***

```
-1 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
```

*Shouldn't the 'last' variable have the previous iteration's value of 'snap'. But the values are equal. What am I doing wrong here?*

Comment: *"the previous iteration's value of 'snap'."* -- where exactly is this value (not the address of the value, but the value itself) stored during the current iteration?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've now realized my mistake. I was letting the value that the given pointer points to, change without storing the value that was being changed

Answer (score 0):

On the second iteration of your for loop, `snap` points to a dangling pointer. The `int arg` that it points to has fallen out of scope.

While it is a dangling pointer, you dereference it, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: I've made the **arg** variable global. The results didn't seem to change

Comment: @sanity_overflow If you make it global, `snap` is the same as `&arg`, so `*snap` is the same object as `arg`. That is, your code becomes equivalent to assigning `last = arg;` and then printing `last` and `arg`.